# Tratar funções que retornam múltiplos valores em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, return

Por exemplo, tenho uma função `mergeSort(alist)`que possui retorno

`return count, blist`

ou seja, retorna um inteiro que é o contador de inversões e uma lista de valores.

Ao passar uma lista `5 4 3 1 2 5` e fazer `print(mergeSort(lista))`, é impresso

`(5, ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])`.

Como pegar apenas o inteiro (`5`) do contador?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enquanto eu escrevia a pergunta me ocorreu algo muito simples, testei e funcionou então resolvi continuar a pergunta e deixar a resposta pro caso de alguém ter a mesma dúvida.

Considerando o exemplo, basta fazer

```
x, y = mergeSort(entrada)
    print(x)
```

E assim o x recebe o primeiro retorno e o y o segundo, sendo que podem ser mais variáveis de acordo com a quantidade de retornos da função.

Comment: Isso se chama `unpacking(desempacotar)`